# When to use FOR UPDATE in SQL Queries?

Tags: php, mysql

Can anyone please tell the difference between the following sql,

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE
```

VS

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE FOR UPDATE
```

**When and at what situation i need to use For Update**

It is taking more time for getting the data if i use update and getting stopped. What is happening on Update to increase the time. Please tell me the entire process happening on this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8849518/mysql-select-for-update-behaviour

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the sentence from the MariaDB / MySQL manual is self-explanatory:

`If you use FOR UPDATE with a storage engine that uses page or row locks, rows examined by the query are write-locked until the end of the current transaction.`

Comment: Why it takes more time for that For Update? Can you please tell me the exact thing happening?

Comment: @VinothBabu when a transaction happens it puts everything in a temporary state/storage before, during, and after - so it is doing much more I/O and also more processing. Transaction logs can get HUGE (especially on big tables)

Comment: It takes time and resources to obtain that lock, Vinoth.

Comment: Thanks frds for your comments and answers.. :)

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` acquires write locks on objects (rows, pages, depending on engine). This  involves some overhead. Additionally, the database (the InnoDB engine in most cases) needs to do additional book keeping for multi-version concurrency control (MVCC).

See the [MySQL documentation on SELECT ... FOR UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-locking-reads.html) for in-depth information and examples.