# spring integration jdbc adapter for multiple nodes

Tags: spring-integration

I'm using the jdbc inbound-channel-adapter with a typical configuration as below to retrieve records from MYSQL DB. The question is how to make the jdbc inbound-channel-adapter work in a multiple nodes environment? Different nodes will have chance to get one same record to process. I know this may be a old questions but I cannot find the resolution so far.

```
<int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter query="select * from messages where state='NEW'"
    channel="jdbcChannel" data-source="datasource" update="update messages set state='PROCESSING' where id in (:id)"
    row-mapper="messageRowMapper" max-rows-per-poll="1">
</int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you should supply transactions for the `<poller>` as Gary pointed, but in addition you should guaranty that one transaction will block another until it finishes. For this purpose you should supply your `SELECT` with `FOR UPDATE` or `LOCK IN SHARE MODE` hints.

More info is in [MySQL Docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-locking-reads.html) or in this answer: [MySQL 'select for update' behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8849518/mysql-select-for-update-behaviour) .

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [transactions](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/jdbc.html#d4e8198); also see [the appendix about transactions](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/transactions.html).