# Spring int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter transaction

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-jdbc

I have gone through this link
[spring integration jdbc adapter for multiple nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30098617/spring-integration-jdbc-adapter-for-multiple-nodes).Which is quite helpful.I have doubt on below point.

I have multi thread environment(Multiple Nodes),where a select query which has n rows eligible,but I have configure max-rows-per-poll=5,followed by a update for these 5 records.
Poller is configure with transaction.

while these 5 records are processed bye one thread in one node,all other thread will wait or they will pick 5 records each from n-5 records and process ?

I am using int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter and Oracle Database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to read about a difference between `max-messages-per-poll` and `max-rows`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.7.RELEASE/reference/html/jdbc.html#jdbc-max-rows-per-poll-versus-max-messages-per-poll.

Also for Oracle I would recommend to use `FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED` if you really would like to get new records and don’t wait for already locked.

Comment: Thanks @Bilan for the answer.

Comment: @Bilan If 2 node at exact time(Same seconds and millisecond) try to access same data returned by select query how to handle that. Between 2 node ,how to priorities one.

Comment: Please, read what is `FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED` in Oracle. You don’t need anything else to configure