# MySQL InnoDB "SELECT FOR UPDATE" - SKIP LOCKED equivalent

Tags: mysql, sql, multithreading, concurrency, innodb

**Is there any way to skip "locked rows" when we make "SELECT FOR UPDATE" in MySQL with an InnoDB table?**

E.g.: terminal t1

```
mysql> start transaction;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select id from mytable ORDER BY id ASC limit 5 for update;
+-------+
| id    |
+-------+
|     1 |
|    15 |
| 30217 |
| 30218 |
| 30643 |
+-------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

At the same time, terminal t2:

```
mysql> start transaction;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select id from mytable where id>30643 order by id asc limit 2 for update;
+-------+
| id    |
+-------+
| 30939 |
| 31211 |
+-------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> select id from mytable order by id asc limit 5 for update;
ERROR 1205 (HY000): Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction
mysql>
```

So if I launch a query forcing it to select other rows, it's fine.

But is there a way to skip the locked rows?

I guess this should be a redundant problem in the concurrent process, but I did not find any solution.

---

**EDIT**: 
In reality, my different concurrent processes are doing something apparently really simple:

1. take the first rows (which don't contain a specific flag - e.g.: "WHERE myflag_inUse!=1").
2. Once I get the result of my "select for update", I update the flag and commit the rows.

So I just want to select the rows which are not already locked and where myflag_inUse!=1...

---

The following link helps me to understand why I get the timeout, but not how to avoid it:

[MySQL 'select for update' behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8849518/mysql-select-for-update-behaviour)

---

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%version%";
+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| Variable_name           | Value                   |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| innodb_version          | 5.5.46                  |
| protocol_version        | 10                      |
| slave_type_conversions  |                         |
| version                 | 5.5.46-0ubuntu0.14.04.2 |
| version_comment         | (Ubuntu)                |
| version_compile_machine | x86_64                  |
| version_compile_os      | debian-linux-gnu        |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Just don't use `SELECT FOR UPDATE`. Taking update locks for a long time is a bad idea and really only useful when using cursors (not a good idea either). You *can't* use it to emulate a checkin/checkout mechanism

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I don't want to emulate this mechanism. I just want to select for update by skipping the locked rows.

Comment: Fix the other transaction so it does not take so long!

Comment: @RickJames, what do you mean by fixing the transaction? commit/rollback?? if yes, actually I have a quite complex sql query running, and this is already taking some time... So all the concurrent requests are always waiting on the other select for update queries...

Comment: Show us the other transaction; let's discuss what can be done for it.  That is, this question is "blaming the victim"; let's go after the "villain".

Comment: It looks like this might be right around the corner:
Facebook has a patch for 5.6:
https://github.com/facebook/mysql-5.6/commit/193896c466d43fd905a62a60f1d73fd9c551a6e4

Answer (score 11, accepted):

MySQL 8.0 introduced support for both `SKIP LOCKED` and `NO WAIT`.

`SKIP LOCKED` is useful for implementing a job queue (a.k.a batch queue) so that you can skip over locks that are already locked by a concurrent transaction.

`NO WAIT` is useful for avoiding waiting until a concurrent transaction releases the locks that we are also interested in locking.

Without `NO WAIT`, we either have to wait until the locks are released (at commit or release time by the transaction that currently holds the locks) or the lock acquisition times out. `NO WAIT` acts as a lock timeout with a value of `0`.

For more details about [`SKIP LOCK`](https://vladmihalcea.com/database-job-queue-skip-locked/) and `NO WAIT`.

Answer (score 6):

This appears to now exist in MySQL starting in 8.0.1:

https://mysqlserverteam.com/mysql-8-0-1-using-skip-locked-and-nowait-to-handle-hot-rows/

> Starting with MySQL 8.0.1 we are introducing the SKIP LOCKED modifier
>   which can be used to non-deterministically read rows from a table
>   while skipping over the rows which are locked.  This can be used by
>   our booking system to skip orders which are pending.  For example:

However, I think that version is not necessarily production ready.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, **it seems that there is no way to skip the locked row in a select for update so far.**

It would be great if we could use something like the Oracle 'FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED'.

In my case, the queries launched in parallel are both exactly the same, and contain a 'where' clause and a 'group by' on a several millions of rows...because the queries need between 20 and 40 seconds to run, that was (as I already knew) a big part of the problem.

**The only -*temporary and not the best*- solution I saw** was to move some (i.e.: millions of) rows that I would not (directly) use in order to **reduce the time the query will take**.

So I will still have the same behavior but I will wait less time...

**I was expecting a way to not select the locked row in the select.**

I don't mark this as an answer, so if a new clause from mysql is added (or discovered), I can accept it later...

Comment: i have the same problem on mysql 5.7 and i am struggling to find a solution. my table is acting as a queue. i have multiple threads reading data from the table to process rows one row at a time. therefore my query uses 'limit 1 for update'. i agree it apears there is no way to skip the locked rows except in mysql8 onwards

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, but I think you approach the problem from a wrong angle. If your user wants to list records from a table that satisfy certain selection criteria, then your query should return them all, or return with an error message and provide no resultset whatsoever. But the query should not reurn only a subset of the results leading the user to belive that he has all the matching records.

The issue should be addressed by making sure that your application locks as few rows as possible, for as little time as possible.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But, in my case, I have several processes running in //. They update data on mytable. I only want to update some data in order to be able to launch several threads in //, and make the global update faster. Of course I have extra condtions in the real where clause, but I only show a simple example here.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I cannot possibly comment on a design I'm not familiar with. You need to take a look at your processes and evaluate whether the way they are locking records is appropriate or even the way those processes are designed is adequate.

Comment: OK. Well my different concurrent processes are doing something apparently really simple: take the first rows (which don't contain a specific flag). Once I get the result of my "select for update", I update the flag and commit the rows. So I just want to select the rows which are not already locked...

Comment: @Bast the "really simple" thing is actually a complex operation - you are trying to emulate a checkin/checkout operation. You can't emulate this with update locks as you found out. Not only will you run into timeouts, your application will have to keep a connection open for the entire duration of the operation. That's a bad idea if you try to do the long running operation on a different machine

Comment: @Bast Then use a flag field instead of locking and either an isolation mode that allows you to see uncommited changes or update the flag fields outside of the long lasting transactions.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, so what do you propose?

Comment: @Shadow, that's exactely what I did (see my previous comment). My transaction is only to update the flag. Then I commit (or rollback if some errors happen...). What do you mean by "isolation mode"... Mutex or something like that? because I would also lose time if so.

Comment: @Bast search for mysql isolation level and you will see what I mean. But I would commit the transaction on the flag field to indicate which records a process is going to process. By flag field I meant a field that flags that a record is being processed.

Comment: @Shadow, I am already doing this (update a flag). That's what I told you in my two previous commits + in my EDIT. BTW: the isolation mode seems interseting - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set-transaction.html

Answer (score 0):

Walk through the table in chunks of the `PRIMARY KEY`, using some suitable `LIMIT` so you are not looking at "too many" rows at once.

By using the PK, you are ordering things in a predictable way; this virtually eliminates deadlocks.

By using `LIMIT`, you will keep from hogging too much at once.  The `LIMIT` should be embodied as a range over the PK.  This makes it quite clear if two threads are about to step on each other.

More details are (indirectly) in my [blog on big deletes](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig).

Comment: thanks for your answer. Actually, this could be the solution when you are in a mono-process program... As I said, I have different concurrent processes, and the goal is to cross the entire DB. But there is no way to know which thread is selecting/locking which rows at a time t.

Comment: True.  And my suggestion will still encounter lock_waits and maybe deadlocks.  However, my suggestion will, I hope, greatly decrease the locking, thereby making the entire process tolerable.

Comment: Yes, as I said in my answer below (http://stackoverflow.com/a/33515992/5165343), I moved millions of "useless rows" to a separate table in order to save some time...